Highlighting searched text across components/elements in react
I have written this component to highlight the searched text within a text or children elements.
Its working fine and searching properly when the text is matched in self or in child element(s) or component(s)
const escapeRegExp = (str = "") => str.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");

export const Highlight = ({ search = "", children }) => {
  const highlightText = (text) => {
    if (!search) return text;

    const pattern = new RegExp(`(${escapeRegExp(search)})`, "i");
    const parts = text.split(pattern);

    return parts.map((part, index) =>
      pattern.test(part) ? <mark key={index}>{part}</mark> : part
    );
  };

  const processChildren = (child) => {
    if (typeof child === "string") {
      return highlightText(child);
    }

    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        children: React.Children.map(child.props.children, processChildren),
      });
    }

    return child; // Return as is for other types (e.g., null, undefined)
  };

  return <>{React.Children.map(children, processChildren)}</>;
};

And I am using it like this:
<Highlight search={searchText}>
  Here's some text{" "}
  <span>
    I don't know if{" "}
    <b>
      this will be searched. I am <>hoping it</> to
    </b>{" "}
    work
  </span>
</Highlight>


The problem is if I search for text which is partly in parent/child component then it fails to search
eg:
if I search for "I am hoping it to" then it fails to highlight the text. I am looking for some solution similar to browser search on chrome (cmd/ctrl+f) If I need to make it work what should I do?


in order to search the text of the children as one string, you would need to strip out the nested raw text of each in "processChildren".  unfortunately, you would then lose the html structure.  i believe you may need to rethink this component or how you generate its children.
technically, you could probably parse the raw html of the children and assign "" tags in and around the other tags, but that would likely be more work than it is worth and VERY bug prone.
